# writing an alias in ./profile for Mac

Tags: macos

I am trying to install a program, it needs an alias to be written in `./profile`. I am a linux user but i do not know how to do that **from Mac terminal**. 
If ./profile doesn't exist and it may be created, where should i create it?

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's referring to `~/.profile` rather than `./profile`.
If it doesn't exist, just create it.  If that doesn't work, try `~/.bash_profile` (assuming you're using the default bash as your shell).

Comment: It is also possible to use ~/.bashrc. If you're using another shell this might be different (e.g. ~/.zshrc for zsh)